# Proving that two affine subspaces of $R^n$ are affine related

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

I am a beginner in Affine Geometry and I always have problems with proving something. So I have problems with this exercise:

**There are two affine subspaces $H_1$ and $H_2$ in an affine space $R^n$. I have to prove that there exists an affine map $\phi$: $R^n \rightarrow R^n$ between these two subspaces.**

I follow the book "Geometry", Audin. So, first, I assume that there is a map between $H_1$ and $H_2$. Then, I have to prove that it is affine. So I think that I have to use the relation $\vec{\phi}$($\vec{OM}$) = $\vec{\phi(O)\circ\phi(M)}$, where O and M belong to $R^n$, to prove that $\phi$ is affine. But after that I am really stuck.

Please, give me a hint what to do. I know it should be trivial, but I really have no idea.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun, Thank you for your advice!